# Use dynamic datatype in LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, dataset

Have a Linq query as following which works:

```
from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable() select row.Field<string>("myDataColumn")
```

Now try to make it work with any column data type (not just `string`). Tried the following:

```
from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable() select row.Field<myDataTable.Columns["myDataColumn"].DataType>("myDataColumn")
```

But it doesn't work.

So is there a way to make the data type dynamic in this particular Linq query?

Comment: That's not how generics work. Generics require specifying the type at compile time, so you can work with that type at compile time. If you don't or can't use that, don't use generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Field` property is designed for getting the value when you know the type at compile time.  When you don't just use the indexer:

```
from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable() select row["myDataColumn"];
```

This will return the value as an `object`.

Comment: You could also just use `Field<object>["..."]` if you wanted.